# How to run CodedUI tests under a particular test user account?

Tags: testing, tfs, tfsbuild, coded-ui-tests

When my CodedUi tests (VS 2012) are run as part of TFS build process, they are run under a BuildUser account. The BuildUser account is used to run builds.

I expected that given the Test Agent is running under a TestUser account, the tests too should be run under the TestUser account.

Is there are a way to run tests as a TestUser, even though the tests are run as part of a TFS build-deploy process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you are running your tests as a part of *build* the tests are run under the context of the build account. While there is no existing configuration such an ask you can achieve this via

1. Modifying the build process template to run the test activity under testUser cred
2. Schedule the run on a test controller which has an agent configured under the testUser cred. This can be done by specifying a .testsettings file with your tests in the build process template. The .testsettings UI in VS will allow you to point to a remote test controller.

When you run your tests as a part of the *build-deploy-test workflow* using labdefaulttemplate then the tests are executed on the environment in the context of the test agent which can be configured as a testUser

Comment: Thank you very much, Allen. I will try your 1st advice: Modifying the build process template to run the test activity under testUser cred

Comment: Allen, could you please advise what should be changed in the Build Template to set a particular TestUser to run tests?
Thanks.

Comment: @stasde I was trying to find a clean way to do this via WF activities but couldnt find something ideal. The brute force way would be to replace the RunTest activity in the build template with one that executes vstest.console as a different user.